# Magento 2 need to get custom module image url from admin

Tags: magento2

I need to get asset image url in block file

Here is my code:

I have image on this page: logo.svg

```
\Abc\Mkt\view\adminhtml\web\images
```

Abc\Mkt\Block\image.php

```
namespace Abc\Mkt\Block;

use Magento\Backend\Block\Template\Context;
use Magento\Config\Block\System\Config\Form\Field;
use Magento\Framework\Data\Form\Element\AbstractElement;

class Image extends Field
{
    /**
     * @var string
     */

    /**
     * @param Context $context
     * @param array $data
     */
    protected $_assetRepo;
    public function __construct(
        Context $context,
        \Magento\Framework\View\Asset\Repository $assetRepo, 
        array $data = []
    ) {
        $this->_assetRepo = $assetRepo;
        parent::__construct($context, $data);
    }

    /**
     * Remove scope label
     *
     * @param  AbstractElement $element
     * @return string
     */
    public function render(AbstractElement $element)
    {
        $image = $this->_assetRepo->getUrl("Abc_Mkt::images/logo.svg");
        $html='<div class="image"><img src='.$image.' style="width:35%;float:right;padding-top: 10px;"></div>';
        return $html;
    }
}
```

Comment: You want to display image in frontend or backend ?

Comment: I want to display image in backend

Comment: @kishan Not getting the image. even distort the page

Comment: Your file is calling did you checked that ?

Comment: yes this is calling

Comment: Print your url and exit and check url proper display or not. It should be working.

Comment: echo $image = $this->_assetRepo->getUrl("Abc_Mkt::images/logo.svg");die;

Comment: check this URL first.

Comment: This is not working

Comment: any errors you're getting there ?

Comment: No, Merely getting blank page

Comment: can you please add this ? **var_dump($image = $this->_assetRepo->getUrl("Abc_Mkt::images/logo.svg"));die;**

Comment: after adding this please refresh page and let me know what you're getting there ?

Comment: Do I need to replace the block file in adminhtml folder?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/101067/discussion-between-shiwani-and-kishan-savaliya).

Comment: @KishanSavaliya did you get any solution?

Answer (score 0):

using this class injection, you can get your image link

> Magento\Framework\View\Asset\Repository $repository,

in your function.

> $this->_repo->createAsset('Abc_Mkt::images/logo.svg')->getUrl();

Comment: This is not working