# Magento2: Need to show image from image asset folder in block file

Tags: magento2

I need to show image from the images asset folder in the 
block file.

> app\code\Abc\Mkt\Block

Here is my file path and code:

```
namespace Abc\Mkt\Block;

use Magento\Backend\Block\Template\Context;
use Magento\Config\Block\System\Config\Form\Field;
use Magento\Framework\Data\Form\Element\AbstractElement;

class Orderfield extends Field
{

    public function __construct(
        Context $context,
        array $data = []
    ) {

        parent::__construct($context, $data);
    }
    public function render(AbstractElement $element)
    {
        $html='<div class="content">
                    <img src="logo.svg" style="width:35%;float:right;padding-top: 10px;"></div>';
        return $html;
    }
}
```

Comment: what you mean by Assets?

Comment: What is difference in this linked question and answer of this question? https://magento.stackexchange.com/q/295754/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use this

```
<?php

namespace Abc\Mkt\Block;

use Magento\Backend\Block\Template\Context;
use Magento\Config\Block\System\Config\Form\Field;
use Magento\Framework\Data\Form\Element\AbstractElement;

class Orderfield extends Field
{
    public function __construct(
        Context $context,
        array $data = []
    ) {
        parent::__construct($context, $data);
    }

    public function render(AbstractElement $element)
    {
        $image = $this->getViewFileUrl('Abc_Mkt::images/logo.png');
        $html='<div class="content">
                    <img src="'.$image.'" style="width:35%;float:right;padding-top: 10px;"></div>';
        return $html;
    }
}
?>
```

Or you can use this

```
<?php

namespace Abc\Mkt\Block;

use Magento\Backend\Block\Template\Context;
use Magento\Config\Block\System\Config\Form\Field;
use Magento\Framework\Data\Form\Element\AbstractElement;

class Orderfield extends Field
{
    protected $_assetRepo;

    public function __construct(
        Context $context,
        array $data = [],
        \Magento\Framework\View\Asset\Repository $assetRepo
    ) {
        $this->_assetRepo = $assetRepo;
        parent::__construct($context, $data);
    }

    public function render(AbstractElement $element)
    {
        $image = $this->_assetRepo->getUrl("Abc_Mkt::images/logo.png");
        $html='<div class="content">
                    <img src="'.$image.'" style="width:35%;float:right;padding-top: 10px;"></div>';
        return $html;
    }
}
?>
```

You need to add your image in your custom module here

> app/code/Abc/Mkt/view/base/web/images/logo.svg

I've added `base` in above path because if you'll add that inside base directory then you will get that image in both frontend and backend using above way.

Hope this will help you!